# Duplicate a file based on files list with sub directories

Tags: file, duplicates, directory

I have a directory with sub directories that contains various files with various sizes
I want to massive duplicate a specific file and replace it with all of them at once.

for example i have:
C:\Folder\Sub_Folder\file1.ext
C:\Folder\Sub_Folder\file2.ext

i want to make a duplicate of "random_file.ext" then replace all the duplicates with the files mentioned above with the original name file1.ext file2.ext so the random_file.ext duplicates becomes the original files.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you use FileChannel class, is more fast and efficient.
Example:

```
try {


        FileInputStream source = new FileInputStream("C:\\Folder\\Sub_Folder\\file1.ext");
        FileOutputStream destination = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Folder\\Sub_Folder\\file3.ext");
        FileChannel sourceChannel = source.getChannel();
        FileChannel destinationChannel = destination.getChannel();
        long size = sourceChannel.size();
        sourceChannel.transferTo(0, size, destinationChannel);


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```